# error: 'projectname' appears as both a file and as a directory

Tags: git

I have a Django project that I am trying to push (from git repo to server)

name of the project is: projectname

the account name is gitlab.com/projectname/django

I am getting this error when I try to push:

```
error: 'projectname' appears as both a file and as a directory
error: projectname: cannot drop to stage #0
error: Pull is not possible because you have unmerged files.
hint: Fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
hint: as appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit.
fatal: Exiting because of an unresolved conflict.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the all process again in a brand new folder (outside of your current repo):

```
cd /another/folder
git clone https://gitlab.com/projectname/django
cd django
```

Then copy the *content* of your previous projectname/django folder in the new django folder.

```
Finally:

cd /another/folder/django
git push
```

Actually, the OP was using ssh URLs, and had to follow "[GitLab and SSH keys](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ssh/README.html) " to make it work.

Comment: restult: root@servername:/home# git clone git@mydomain.com:reponame/django.git
Cloning into 'django'...
git@mydomain.com's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.

Comment: @MoAlgh Do you have the right ssh keys in ~root/.ssh?

Comment: @MoAlgh You can test it with (as root) `ssh -Tv git@mydomain.com`

Comment: I see a lot of line start with debug1 i don't know if some of them contain keys. keys are suppose to be long. i see texts like this fDFgsSfGRws and they are short

Comment: Do you have ~root/.ssh/id_rsa and ~root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub?

Comment: After entering the password:
debug1: getpeername failed: Transport endpoint is not connected
Authenticated to mydomain.com ([UNKNOWN]:-1).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
packet_write_wait: Connection to XXX.XXX.XXX.XX port 22: Broken pipe

Comment: cd /.ssh/id_rsa.pub
-bash: cd: /.ssh/id_rsa.pub: No such file or directory

Comment: There you go. Make sure that You can reach your remote server (ping), generate your keys, and register your public one to your gitlab account.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little please?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
git add projectname
git commit -m "Fixing 'projectname appears as both a file and as a directory' error"
git push origin master
```

Comment: result: error: unable to index file projectname
fatal: updating files failed